# JavaFX: Move Camera Around A Pivot Point Unexpected Behaviour

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-3d

I'm currently trying to rotate a Perspective Camera around a pivot point (0,0,0) however I'm getting undesirable results. The camera itself is rotating its view rather than translating the camera.

I would therefore like it to always look towards the pivot point (0,0,0) and translate itself around that point.

Currently, I'm seeing this behaviour translating in the Z axis:

[image: Z Axis]

And this in the Y Axis:

[image: Y Axis]

Code:

```
private Rotate rotation;
private Translate pivot;
Camera camera = new PerspectiveCamera(true);

pivot = new Translate(0,0,0);

stage.addEventHandler(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, event -> {
        if(event.getCode() == KeyCode.A){
            rotation = new Rotate(-1, 0,0,0, Rotate.Z_AXIS);
        }
        if(event.getCode() == KeyCode.D){
            rotation = new Rotate(1, 0,0,0, Rotate.Z_AXIS);
        }
        if(event.getCode() == KeyCode.W){
            rotation = new Rotate(-1, pivot.getX(), pivot.getY(), pivot.getZ(), Rotate.Y_AXIS);
        }
        if(event.getCode() == KeyCode.S){
            rotation = new Rotate(1, pivot.getX(), pivot.getY(), pivot.getZ(), Rotate.Y_AXIS);
        }
        camera.getTransforms().add(rotation);
        System.out.println("Camera: x"+camera.getTranslateX()+" y:"+camera.getTranslateY()+" z:"+camera.getTranslateZ());
    });
```

Comment: Are we supposed to debug code we cannot see?

Comment: @TheHeadRush oops hahaha, I forgot to paste it in!

Comment: @TheHeadRush Added it in now!

Comment: Why are you accumulating new `Rotate` transforms, instead of applying one single one and modifying its properties (angle, pivot, axis)?

Comment: @JoséPereda oh! I didn’t know you could do that, so how would you go about that then?

Comment: As I mentioned, create global `Rotate` objects, and add them once. Then just modify their properties as required, like in this [sample](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52020701/3956070).

Comment: Okay, changing that still doesn't change the behavior though!