# How to get 2D scene coordinates of a 3D object in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, 3d, coordinates, fxyz3d

I'm trying the create a 3D subscene with objects being labelled using Label objects in a 2D overlay.  I've seen similar questions to mine on this subject, and they all point to using the Node.localToScene method on the node to be labelled in the 3D space. But this doesn't seem to work for my case.  I've taken example code from the FXyz FloatingLabels example here:

[FloatingLabels.java](https://github.com/FXyz/FXyz/blob/master/FXyz-Samples/src/main/java/org/fxyz3d/samples/utilities/FloatingLabels.java)

The Label objects need to have their positions updated as the 3D scene in modified, which I've done but when I print out the coordinates returned by the Node.localToScene method, they're much too large to be within the application scene, and so the labels are never visible in the scene.  I've written an example program that illustrates the issue, set up very similarly to the FXyz sample code but I've created an extra SubScene object to hold the 2D and 3D SubScene objects in order to plant them into a larger application window with slider controls.  The 3D scene uses a perspective camera and shows a large sphere with coloured spheres along the x/y/z axes, and some extra little nubs on the surface for reference:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.PerspectiveCamera;
import javafx.scene.SubScene;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.SceneAntialiasing;
import javafx.scene.AmbientLight;
import javafx.scene.PointLight;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.Slider;
import javafx.scene.control.ToolBar;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Priority;
import javafx.scene.shape.Sphere;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.paint.PhongMaterial;
import javafx.scene.transform.Rotate;
import javafx.scene.transform.Translate;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.geometry.Point3D;

import java.util.Map;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class LabelTest extends Application {

  private Map<Node, Label> nodeToLabelMap;

  @Override
  public void start (Stage stage) {

    // Create main scene graph

    var objects3d = new Group();

    Rotate xRotate = new Rotate (0, 0, 0, 0, Rotate.X_AXIS);
    Rotate yRotate = new Rotate (0, 0, 0, 0, Rotate.Y_AXIS);
    objects3d.getTransforms().addAll (
      xRotate,
      yRotate
    );

    var root3d = new Group();
    root3d.getChildren().add (objects3d);

    var camera = new PerspectiveCamera (true);
    camera.setTranslateZ (-25);
    
    var scene3d = new SubScene (root3d, 500, 500, true, SceneAntialiasing.BALANCED);
    scene3d.setFill (Color.rgb (20, 20, 80));
    scene3d.setCamera (camera);

    var sceneRoot = new Group (scene3d);
    var objects2d = new Group();
    sceneRoot.getChildren().add (objects2d);
    var viewScene = new SubScene (sceneRoot, 500, 500);

    scene3d.widthProperty().bind (viewScene.widthProperty());
    scene3d.heightProperty().bind (viewScene.heightProperty());

    // Add lights and objects

    var ambient = new AmbientLight (Color.color (0.7, 0.7, 0.7));
    var point = new PointLight (Color.color (0.3, 0.3, 0.3));
    point.setTranslateX (-25);
    point.setTranslateY (-25);
    point.setTranslateZ (-50);
    
    root3d.getChildren().addAll (ambient, point);

    var globe = new Sphere (5);
    globe.setMaterial (new PhongMaterial (Color.color (0.3, 0.3, 0.3)));

    var xSphere = new Sphere (0.5);
    xSphere.setMaterial (new PhongMaterial (Color.RED));
    xSphere.setTranslateX (5);

    var ySphere = new Sphere (0.5);
    ySphere.setMaterial (new PhongMaterial (Color.GREEN));
    ySphere.setTranslateY (5);

    var zSphere = new Sphere (0.5);
    zSphere.setMaterial (new PhongMaterial (Color.BLUE));
    zSphere.setTranslateZ (5);
    
    objects3d.getChildren().addAll (globe, xSphere, ySphere, zSphere);

    var nubMaterial = new PhongMaterial (Color.color (0.2, 0.2, 0.2));
    for (int i = 0; i < 200; i++) {
      var nub = new Sphere (0.125);
      nub.setMaterial (nubMaterial);
      var phi = 2*Math.PI*Math.random();
      var theta = Math.acos (2*Math.random() - 1);
      var z = -5 * Math.sin (theta) * Math.cos (phi);
      var x = 5 * Math.sin (theta) * Math.sin (phi);
      var y = -5 * Math.cos (theta);
      nub.setTranslateX (x);
      nub.setTranslateY (y);
      nub.setTranslateZ (z);
      objects3d.getChildren().add (nub);
    } // for

    // Add labels

    var xLabel = new Label ("X axis");
    xLabel.setTextFill (Color.RED);

    var yLabel = new Label ("Y axis");
    yLabel.setTextFill (Color.GREEN);

    var zLabel = new Label ("Z axis");
    zLabel.setTextFill (Color.BLUE);

    objects2d.getChildren().addAll (xLabel, yLabel, zLabel);

    nodeToLabelMap = new HashMap<>();
    nodeToLabelMap.put (xSphere, xLabel);
    nodeToLabelMap.put (ySphere, yLabel);
    nodeToLabelMap.put (zSphere, zLabel);

    xRotate.angleProperty().addListener ((obs, oldVal, newVal) -> updateLabels());
    yRotate.angleProperty().addListener ((obs, oldVal, newVal) -> updateLabels());
    camera.translateZProperty().addListener ((obs, oldVal, newVal) -> updateLabels());
    Platform.runLater (() -> updateLabels());

    // Create main pane

    var gridPane = new GridPane();
    
    var stackPane = new StackPane (viewScene);
    viewScene.heightProperty().bind (stackPane.heightProperty());
    viewScene.widthProperty().bind (stackPane.widthProperty());
    viewScene.setManaged (false);

    gridPane.add (stackPane, 0, 0);
    gridPane.setVgrow (stackPane, Priority.ALWAYS);
    gridPane.setHgrow (stackPane, Priority.ALWAYS);

    // Add controls

    var xSlider = new Slider (-90, 90, 0);
    xRotate.angleProperty().bind (xSlider.valueProperty());
    var ySlider = new Slider (-180, 180, 0);
    yRotate.angleProperty().bind (ySlider.valueProperty());
    var zSlider = new Slider (-60, -25, -25);
    camera.translateZProperty().bind (zSlider.valueProperty());

    ToolBar toolbar = new ToolBar (
      new Label ("X rotation:"),
      xSlider,
      new Label ("Y rotation:"),
      ySlider,
      new Label ("Z position:"),
      zSlider
    );
    gridPane.add (toolbar, 0, 1);

    // Start the show

    stage.setTitle ("Label Test");
    stage.setScene (new Scene (gridPane, 800, 600));
    stage.show();

  } // start
  
  private void updateLabels () {
    
    nodeToLabelMap.forEach ((node, label) -> {
      var coord = node.localToScene (Point3D.ZERO, true);
      System.out.println ("label = " + label.getText() + ", coord = " + coord);
      label.getTransforms().setAll (new Translate(coord.getX(), coord.getY()));
    });

  } // updateLabels
  
  public static void main (String[] args) {

    launch (args);

  } // main

} // LabelTest class
```

You can compile and run the LabelTest.java program using this script (I'm using JavaFX 14 and JDK 14.0.2 on a Mac):

```
#!/bin/sh

set -x

export PATH_TO_FX=javafx-sdk-14/lib

javac --module-path $PATH_TO_FX --add-modules javafx.controls LabelTest.java
if [ $? -ne 0 ] ; then
  exit 1
fi

java -cp . --module-path $PATH_TO_FX --add-modules javafx.controls LabelTest
```

My test program output contains very large label coordinates that don't represent the position of the coloured axis spheres, for example:

```
label = Y axis, coord = Point3D [x = 17448.00808897467, y = 21535.846392310217, z = 0.0]
label = X axis, coord = Point3D [x = 26530.33870777918, y = 12453.515773505665, z = 0.0]
label = Z axis, coord = Point3D [x = 17448.008088974653, y = 12453.515773505665, z = 0.0]
```

My display looks like this:

[image: Label Test Screenshot]

where as it should look more like the example from FXyz with labels next to the axis spheres:

[image: FXyz Floating Labels Screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you follow what has been done in the [link](https://github.com/FXyz/FXyz/blob/master/FXyz-Samples/src/main/java/org/fxyz3d/samples/utilities/FloatingLabels.java) you have posted you'll make it work.

For starters, there is one subScene, not two.

So I've removed these lines:

```
-        var viewScene = new SubScene (new Group (scene3d), 500, 500);

-        scene3d.widthProperty().bind (viewScene.widthProperty());
-        scene3d.heightProperty().bind (viewScene.heightProperty());
```

and replaced these:

```
-    var stackPane = new StackPane (viewScene);
-    viewScene.heightProperty().bind (stackPane.heightProperty());
-    viewScene.widthProperty().bind (stackPane.widthProperty());
-    viewScene.setManaged (false);

+    var stackPane = new StackPane (sceneRoot);
+    scene3d.heightProperty().bind (stackPane.heightProperty());
+    scene3d.widthProperty().bind (stackPane.widthProperty());
```

That works fine now for me:

```
label = Z axis, coord = Point3D [x = 613.2085772621016, y = 286.33580935946725, z = 0.0]
label = X axis, coord = Point3D [x = 401.67010722785966, y = 219.90328164976754, z = 0.0]
label = Y axis, coord = Point3D [x = 400.0, y = 503.57735384935296, z = 0.0]
```

[image: rotations]

Comment: Thank you! I just wish I understood better why the original code didn't work and how sub scenes work.  I've looked at the JavaFX API but for whatever reason I don't seem to really grasp what's going on behind the scenes in terms of coordinate transformations up the branches of the scene graph.

Comment: It's a complex process, but at the end it's all a bunch of matrix transforms... but the problem is finding out how to do it (the camera, the sub scene, the transform for each node, ... are involved). A while ago I posted this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52020701/3956070). What was used before the edit worked fine and might explain better how things are done internally.

Comment: Something misleading to me is the documentation for the localToScene​(Point3D localPoint, boolean rootScene) method.  Since we're specifying rootScene=true, the documentation says it returns a coordinate relative to the scene.  These coordinates that we're using to update the label positions are relative to the top-left corner of the panel holding the 3D scene (ie: the subscene within the overall scene), not the top-left corner of the overall scene returned by getScene().  I did actually read your previous posted solution and edit.  In any case, thank you so much for your help!